# Why does mysql slow log reports these non-slow queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

My mysql server has `long_query_time = 2` configured but I still see these queries reported in slow query log that seem fast:

```
# Time: 120730  5:06:41
# User@Host: <user> @ <Host> [<IP>] 
# Query_time: 0.000412  Lock_time: 0.000060 Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 5
SET timestamp=1343639201;
SELECT album_id FROM `TB_albums` where album_id!='res_4fe4333271bda7.42833845' and deleted is NULL order by `created_time` desc limit 5;
```

As you can see Query_time: 0.000412  Lock_time: 0.000060  seems way below 2 seconds

Do you have any Idea why these "*fast*" queries are reported?

Comment: have you checked for variable log_queries_not_using_indexes?

Comment: @Omesh - checked and this is exactly the problem, I wonder what I can index here???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### MySQL also logs queries which do not use an index

The option `log-queries-not-using-indexes` in my.cnf is used to control this. Mine is turned off (by commenting out) as you can see from this snippet of my.cnf

```
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

If you don't have access to the my.cnf, you can check using SQL

```
mysql> show variables like 'log_queries_not_using_indexes';
+-------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                 | Value |
+-------------------------------+-------+
| log_queries_not_using_indexes | OFF   |
+-------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope that helps!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

check for variable `log-queries-not-using-indexes`

```
show variables like '%log_queries_not_using_indexes%';
+-------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                 | Value |
+-------------------------------+-------+
| log_queries_not_using_indexes | OFF   | 
+-------------------------------+-------+
```

for your case it must be set to OFF, if ON then you can set `log_queries_not_using_indexes = OFF` in `my.cnf` file and then restart the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK MySQL measures the query time for a data-fetching query from query submission up to the end of the fetch phase.this means, that something like

```
Start timer
Start fast SELECT query
Wait for result 
Check timer and note time
sleep 2 seconds
fetch query results
Stop timer
```

will end up with `noted time<2s` and `end time>2s`, and the slow query log triggering on the longer time.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html), you need to check the other config that related to write a query to the show query log.

The server uses the controlling parameters in the following order to determine whether to write a query to the slow query log:

> 1.The query must either not be an administrative statement, or
>   --log-slow-admin-statements must have been specified.
>
> 2.The query must have taken at least long_query_time seconds, or log_queries_not_using_indexes must be enabled and the query used no
>   indexes for row lookups.
>
> 3.The query must have examined at least min_examined_row_limit rows.
>
> 4.The query must not be suppressed according to the log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes setting.